# How to record streams with Ace Player HD?

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-streaming, recording, audio-streaming, p2p

Need help to record an audio/video stream from Ace Player HD program. Uses Ace Stream. It's based on VLC Media Player but seems the record option was removed. Any ideas?

Comment: I found how to do it. You have to open Ace Stream Content ID, and instead of selecting Play, select Stream or Convert and save to file.

Comment: Been testing again and seems a little buggy, it doesn't download from peers as fast as using embedded played within Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 8):

1. Click in the **View** menu of the Ace Player
2. Go to **Advanced controls** (once you click, then advanced controls must appear in the left lower corner).
3. Click on the record button.
4. You can find the recorded video in My Documents or Videos folder
   (You can configure it).